# Fetching Data outside of Effect in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm just wondering, is following approach a good way to fetch data? If not, what would be the problems I will face?

```
const Component = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined)
  if (!data) {
   fetchDataAPI('api/mock-data', (data) => setData(data))
  }
}
```

The data fetching starts by the first render and once it is accomplished, following rerenders wouldn't trigger it anymore.

Comment: Have you tested this?  Did you encounter a problem?  If so, what was it?  I'd argue that this is unconventional and unintuitive and could easily lead a developer to fetch data outside of a `useEffect` in a way that creates an infinite re-render cycle.  For that reason alone I would consider `useEffect` to be more clear about the situation.

Comment: yeah, I've tested it and so far it works well within a small test set, but since I don't have much experience in fetching data in react, I'm inquisitive about what kind of situations I haven't considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you would face is that when an initial API call is made in a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, the component function knows to only execute the code within the useEffect on the first render, whereas if the code is just executed within the function, an unnecessary check on the data is made every render and if for example, the API request fails and the fetch is not handled correctly, then the request will be run over and over each re-render as the `data` will remain undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> what would be the problems I will face?

Besides the fact it's kind of an *anti-pattern* since `useEffect` was created to handle *side effects*, you may also end up with multiple requests sent to API. If the component re-renders while `data` is still `undefined` (the request is still fetching), the API request will be sent again.

This issue is no longer relevant when using `useEffect`, since if empty *dependency* array provided, you are ensured that it will be called **only** once, even if the component re-renders again.